# How can I get access to modify this price function in Magento

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, magento

So I now need to customize the discounted price for my Shopping cart. I'd research it by myself and I realize i can modify the **view.phtml** and **item.phtml** in order to display the right price. But i am not satisfied, therefore my eyes on this line of code:

`<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?>`

I presume this line of code's function is to call the price from somewhere call checkout in helper section and return it. My question is how can i get access to there.

Thank you so much.

**UPDATE 1:**
I did some research after aton gave me some tips then i dive into the file `DATA.php` and found the function he mentioned which is:

```
public function formatPrice($price)
{
    return $this->getQuote()->getStore()->formatPrice($price);
}
```

But is there any way to dive even deeper into `$this->getQuote()->getStore()->formatPrice($price);`

Once again thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you have mentioned above the price is coming from `$_item->getCalculationPrice()`.

The code

`<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?>`

just takes the price and formats it i.e adds the currency symbol according to your store and other things.

If you want to know where is the **formatPrice** function resides navigate to

> app/code/core/Mage/checkout/Helper/Data.php

Here you will see the defination of that function.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Once again thank you, i don't know how to repay you, my good sir.