# Using include method in PHP function in Magento

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, magento

Let's keep it simple so I have my code in **View.phtml** to display javascript element

```
    $Abowl = '<p id="finalprice"></p>';
    echo $Abowl;
```

And now i want to pass this to another PHP name's **DATA.php**, I tried but it's not working

```
 public function formatPrice($price)
{
    include'view.phtml';
    return $this->getQuote()->getStore()->formatPrice($Abowl); 
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**
I tried something like this :

```
public function formatPrice($price)
{
    require_once(Mage::getBaseDir() . '\app\design\frontend\neighborhood\default\template\catalog\product\view.‌​phtml');
    return $this->getQuote()->getStore()->formatPrice($Abowl); //this is the source
}
```

**UPDATE 2 :** I had asked a question which said DATA.php do not accept any outsource variable in here : [How can I get access to modify this price function in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29247520/how-can-i-get-access-to-modify-this-price-function-in-magento/29248999#29248999)
Does it affect me?

**UPDATE 3** : I have modified the function under **\magento\js\varien\product.js** in order to satisfy my client's requirement. It works fine, the discount will apply due to the users information from our database. 
[image]

But when the customer add an item to cart, it only shows the original price which is $549.47 in this example.

[image]

Therefore, i want to pass the javascript result to the DATA.php as well since It is contain the formatPrice function which apply to the shopping cart section

**Here's part of my javascript codes(\magento\js\varien\product.js) which generate the discounted price:**

```
var subPrice = 0; //is the price inside the option
            var subPriceincludeTax = 0;
            var discountRate = discountRateUrl; //discount base on database
            var price = priceUrl;//get the product price
            var discountedPrice = price*discountRate; // price * ourdiscount
            //var discountedSubPrice = subPrice*((100-test)/100); // custom option addition price * ourdiscounted prices
            //console.log(discountedPrice); //display the prices as int
            //console.log(discountedSubPrice);
            //console.log(test);
            Object.values(this.customPrices).each(function(el){
                if (el.excludeTax && el.includeTax) {
                    subPrice += parseFloat(el.excludeTax); // use the var factor && this will affect the price when changing option *important
                    subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.includeTax);

                } else {
                    subPrice += parseFloat(el.price);
                    subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.price);

                }
                var finalprice = (subPrice*discountRate+discountedPrice);//checking if getting the php
                var fomattedprice = finalprice.toFixed(2); //Convert a number into a string, keeping only two decimals
                console.log(finalprice); //tester of the final prices
                console.log(discountRate);//tester discount rate in string
                document.getElementById("finalprice").innerHTML = "<small>Your price is </small>"+ "$" + fomattedprice + "*" +"<br/><small><em>*Discount will be applied during check out</em></small>";
          });
```

You can ignore these bunch of codes, i just want to know where should i pass my `document.getElementById("finalprice");` result in order to show the discounted price.

The follow is my view.html for reference:

```
  <?php 
        //SQL to identify ones email and discount
        $prices = Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice(), $formatPrice, $html);
        echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data');
        if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

        $conn = Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

        //need to change this sql statment to other table, took up and sl.is_active = 1 for test only
        //it won't work by now because method is changed and not connecting to the right DB table
        $sql = 'select sl.discount_amount, scg.customer_group_id, sl.stop_rules_processing from salesrule sl
                join salesrule_customer_group scg on scg.rule_id = sl.rule_id
                join customer_entity ce on ce.group_id = scg.customer_group_id
                where ce.email = "'.$customerData->getemail().'" 
                order by sl.discount_amount desc';
        //and sl.is_active = 1

        //'select sl.discount_amount from salesrule sl 
                //  join salesrule_customer_group scg on scg.rule_id = sl.rule_id
                //  join customer_entity ce on ce.group_id = scg.customer_group_id
                //  where ce.email = "'.$customerData->getemail().'";';

        $results = $conn->fetchAll($sql);

        $Abowl = '<p id="finalprice"></p>';
        echo $Abowl; //only applied when not logged in

        $discountRate = 1;
        foreach ($results as $result)
        {   

            $currentRate = $result['discount_amount'];
            //print_r($currentRate);
            $discountRate = $discountRate*(100 - $currentRate)/100;

            if($result['stop_rules_processing']==1){
                break;
            }

        }

        }   ?>
```

Comment: where   you have keep this file ?

Comment: View.phtml store in : \magento\app\design\frontend\neighborhood\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml

Comment: DATA.php store in : \magento\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Helper\DATA.php

Comment: it should be like   

require_once(Mage::getBaseDir() . ''/app\design\frontend\neighborhood\default\template\catalog\product\view.‌​phtml');

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by the folloeing code

```
require_once(Mage::getBaseDir() . 'path to your file');
```

Mage::getBaseDir()  this will give you the magento base directory url

Comment: Having the same error even copy and pasta the codes u edited, i think yours code is right but seem it can't solve my issues. P.S: I voted you up already

Comment: can you tell me wht you are including the whole product view file in another file ?

Comment: I had some additional information updated, please have a look, you can ignore some needless information. Thank you !